# Mixed JSON with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire to make a POST HTTP request to upload device data to The Things Network in Swift; however, I get an error telling me that "Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols". How would I fix this so I can use this dict?

```swift
    let params: [String : Any] = [
        "altitude": 0,
        "app-id": "some-app-id",
        "attributes" : [
            "key": "",
            "value": ""
        ],
        "description": "some description of the device",
        "dev_id": "some-dev-id",
        "latitude": 52.375,
        "longitude": 4.887,
        "lorawan_device": [
            "activation_constraints": "local",
            "app_eui": "0102030405060708",
            "app_id": "some-app-id",
            "app_key": "01020304050607080102030405060708",
            "app_s_key": "01020304050607080102030405060708",
            "dev_addr": "01020304",
            "dev_eui": "0102030405060708",
            "dev_id": "some-dev-id",
            "disable_f_cnt_check": false,
            "f_cnt_down": 0,
            "f_cnt_up": 0,
            "last_seen": 0,
            "nwk_s_key": "01020304050607080102030405060708",
            "uses32_bit_f_cnt": true
        ]
    ]

AF.request("{url}", method: .post, parameters: params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted).response { response in
        print(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `[String: Any]` does not confirm `Encodable`.

Replace

```
AF.request("{url}", method: .post, parameters: params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted).response { response in
        print(response)
}
```

to

```
AF.request("{url}", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted).response { response in
        print(response)
}
```

Comment: From [Documentations](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-requests): **"There are additional methods that allow you to make requests using Parameters dictionaries and ParameterEncoding types. This API is no longer recommended and will eventually be deprecated and removed from Alamofire."** It will be removed so how it will be done after that?